# Qt: QGraphicsView content not erased before drawForeground() is called

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, repaint, qgraphicsview

I'm facing an annoying issue using Qt QGraphicsView framework.
I write a basic image viewer to display large B&W tiff images.
Images are displayed using a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and added to the scene.

I also need to draw a colored rectangle around the viewport.

```
void ImageView::drawForeground( QPainter * painter, const QRectF & rect )
{
    if( m_image ) {
        qDebug() << "drawForeground(), rect = " << rect;
        QBrush br(m_image->isValidated() ? Qt::green : Qt::red);

        qreal w = 40. / m_scaleFactor;

        QPen pen(br, w);
        painter->save();
        painter->setOpacity(0.5);
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->drawRect(rect);
        painter->restore();
    }
}
```

It works fine, at first glance.

But when I scroll the viewport content, things are getting ugly.
`drawForeground()` method is effectively called but it seems the content of the viewport is not erased before. So the drawing becomes horrible on screen.

Is there a better way to achieve it?

**EDIT**

As leems mentioned it, Qt internals don't alow me to achieve it with drawForeground().
I found a workaround by using a **QGraphicsRectItem** which gets resized in the viewportEvent().
Loos like:

```
bool ImageView::viewportEvent(QEvent *ev)
{
    QRect rect = viewport()->rect();

    if( m_image ) {
        QPolygonF r = mapToScene(rect);
        QBrush br2(m_image->isValidated() ? Qt::green : Qt::red);
        qreal w2 = 40. / m_scaleFactor;
        QPen pen2(br2, w2);
        m_rect->setPen(pen2);
        m_rect->setOpacity(0.5);
        m_rect->setRect(r.boundingRect());
    }

    return QGraphicsView::viewportEvent(ev);
}
```

The code is not finalized but will basically looks like that.
It works fine, though it blinks a little bit when scrolling too fast...

Comment: You're inconsistent: In the title you say it's not called, but in the text you say it's called. If you already guess that the problem is a missing clearing, you probably need to set some flag (let me find it...)

Comment: Wait, you use `rect` for drawing. I guess that if you scroll, only the part of the screen which was previously not visible, and now is visible, will be passed to this function. If you want a rect around the whole view, you better put it in a wrapper widget with some background color for that... Use a layout with some margin to fill it in the wrapper with the spacing you want.

Comment: you're right... I just changed it. I'm using graphicsview for a long time but never had to use drawForeground(). I already thought about using a rectangle item but drawForeground() came to mind naturally as I indeed want to draw something on the  foreground  :)

Comment: The problem is that the view assumes that the foreground (as well as the background) doesn't change. You want a rect on the visible part, so scrolling "changes" the foreground (where previously was an edge of your rect, it might no longer be!). So the algorithms in Qt don't work anymore, which only update part of the screen when needed (which is exactly what happens if you scroll). You could also simply enforce the whole view to be updated when scrolled, I guess you can do that with a simple connect statement (from the scroll bar's valueChanged to the view's update) but that sounds like a hack

Comment: Unfortunately I came to the same conclusion as I debugged the source-code of QGraphicsView...I could of course connect an update() statement to some scrolling signal but as you noticed...it's a hack.